# How to get a positive signal upon the successful completion of a command

Tags: command-line, terminal

For each of the following commands (four in total) I would like get an exception if one of them throws an exception if case of an error. Ultimately, I will run this through Python using os.system().

```
import os

x =\
    "../../../mysql/bin/mysqldump\
    --host=localhost\
    --port=3306\
    --databases ****\
    --user=****\
    --password=****\
    --default-character-set=utf8\
    --add-drop-database\
    --add-drop-table\
    --add-locks\
    --complete-insert\
    --extended-insert\
    --lock-all-tables\
    --create-options\
    --disable-keys\
    --quick\
    --order-by-primary\
    --set-charset\
    --tz-utc\
    > dump/test.sql;\
    cd dump;\
    tar -zcf test.sql.tar.gz test.sql;\
    rm test.sql;"

os.system(x)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should run the commands individually from python to catch the exceptions. Look at `subprocess.check_output()` or install `plumbum` and use that.

Comment: os.system is obsolete. Use the subprocess module. What Anthon said.

Comment: Depending on you python version, you can also try python commands lib, for checking return codes of a command. https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html

Comment: @user706838 Hi, I an using Python 3.4

Comment: Then better use the solution @Anthon gave

Comment: @Anthon Sure! But why not using subprocess.call() instead? Also, as far as I can see, both of them require **shell=True** be enabled, however, documentation claims that **Using shell=True can be a security hazard.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that with "for each of the commands" you mean `mysqldump`, `cd`, `tar` and `rm` and with these throwing an exception meaning an exit status that is not 0 (zero), you should not be using `os.system()` as you do, as it only handles one exit value.

Based on the requirement to have a python exception based on the command finding an error makes `subprocess.check_output()` the prime candidate. It is a thin layer around `subprocess.call()`, but contrary to tha letter `check_output()` throwns and exception on non-zero exit of the command called (`call()` just returns the exit value). In addition `check_output()` hands the commands output to stdout back, which enables chaining the different commands at the python level, or writing out the output to file (as well as providing the possibility for checking for warnings in the programs output that might not trigger a non-zero exit status).

I would do something like

```
test_sql = subprocess.check_output([
 "../../../mysql/bin/mysqldump",
 "--host=localhost",
 "--port=3306",
 "--databases ****",
 "--user=****",
 "--password=****",
 "--default-character-set=utf8",
 "--add-drop-database",
 "--add-drop-table",
 "--add-locks",
 "--complete-insert",
 "--extended-insert",
 "--lock-all-tables",
 "--create-options",
 "--disable-keys",
 "--quick",
 "--order-by-primary",
 "--set-charset",
 "--tz-utc",
])
# analyse test_sql if necessary
with open("dump/test.sql", "w") as fp:
   fp.write(test_sql)
os.chdir('dump')
subprocess.check_output("tar -zcf test.sql.tar.gz test.sql".split())
os.remove("test.sql")
```

Using `check_output()`s [`input` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) (new in Python 3.4) you can also do away with writing the `test.sql` file and hand the `test_sql` directly into the second `check_output()` call. But then you could directly write the tar file from within Python using the `tarfile` module.

With [`plumbum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum) it is easier to follow the structure of your shell program calls, as it supports redirection:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../../../mysql")

from plumbum.cmd import myslqdump
(mysqldump[
  "--host=localhost",
  "--port=3306",
  "--databases ****",
  "--user=****",
  "--password=****",
  "--default-character-set=utf8",
  "--add-drop-database",
  "--add-drop-table",
  "--add-locks",
  "--complete-insert",
  "--extended-insert",
  "--lock-all-tables",
  "--create-options",
  "--disable-keys",
  "--quick",
  "--order-by-primary",
  "--set-charset",
  "--tz-utc",
 ] > "test.sql")()
```

Comment: nice. would it be also possible to do **cd dump** and **rm test.sql** through subprocess.check_output() instead of calling os library? why? why not?

Comment: @user706838 You cannot do the `cd` in a subprocess, because that cd would change the current dir of the invoked program/subshell, and the program would stay in the current directory. You can call rm that way but it boils down to the same system call as python's os.remove() with the extra overhead of creating a subprocess

Comment: It doesn't work I am afraid. I get the following error: **subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command <...> returned non-zero exit status 2** I suspect this is because of the fact that the mysqldump requires the **> dump.sql** otherwise it returns a non-empty value by definition. Any ideas?

Comment: @user706838 I really doubt that dump.sql tries to detect if the output is redirected or not, but you can easily test that from the commandline. You can of course put that whole statement (including redirect) in a bash script that you invoke with `check_output([`bash', `script_name`]), but I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Change those semicolons to `&&` in the command pipeline so that the shell will stop on the first command that fails and return its exit status, then check the return code from os.system().